# Pandas: replace values of a series by lookup of index

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, replace, series

I want to replace some values in a series using a lookup table for certain indices. For example:

```
s1     = Series.(['keep', 'replace', 'replace'}, index=['p1', 'p2', 'p3'])
lookup = {'p2' : 'altered', 'p3' : 'changed'}
# desired series s1:
# p1  keep
# p2  altered
# p3  changed
```

Sure, I could do this by looping over the dict, but I strongly assume there is a better way in pandas.

However, this is only on step of a more complex task. I'd appreciate any suggestions how to achieve the following in the most readable (and efficient) way of pandas.

The goal is to compute a column holding some aggregated information.
For example, I am given a data frame `df` like this:

```
  object color
0     o1    gr
1     o2    gr
2     o2    rd
3     o3    rd
4     1o  None
5     2o  None
6     3o  None
```

Objects are considered similar by some function, e.g. `reverse` (`o1 == 1o`, etc.).
Eventually, I want to add a column `colors` to `df`:

```
  object color    colors
0     o1    gr      {gr}
1     o2    gr  {rd, gr}
2     o2    rd  {rd, gr}
3     o3    rd      {rd}
4     1o  None      {gr}
5     2o  None  {rd, gr}
6     3o  None      {rd}
```

Where `colors` holds a set of of colors for each object. The unknown colors for `1o`, `2o` and `3o` are taken from their siblings.

Currently, I am doing these steps:

```
d = OrderedDict([('object', ['o1', 'o2', 'o2', 'o3', '1o', '2o', '3o']),\
                 ('color',  ['gr', 'gr', 'rd', 'rd', None, None, None])])
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# 1. Group and aggregate the colors.
colors = df.groupby('object')['color'].apply(set)

# 2. Compute a lookup table
colored = df.ix[~pd.isnull(df['color']), 'object'].unique()
unknown = df.ix[pd.isnull(df['color']), 'object'].unique()
lookup  = {obj[::-1] : colors[obj] for obj in colored}

# 3. Set colors of `1o`, ... (Initial Question!)
colors[colors.index.isin(lookup.keys())] = colors.index.to_series().map(lookup)

# 4. Add column `colors` original data frame
df['colors'] = df['object'].map(colors)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your second more complex part but for the first you can do `s1[s1.index.isin(lookup.keys())] = s1.index.to_series().map(lookup)`

Comment: I am confused by this question as well.  Perhaps you should reword it and provide a more concrete example.

Comment: @Alexander: I've overhauled the example significantly, to make things clearer.

Comment: @EdChum: How about the rephrased example?

Comment: @user1722901 did you ever find a solution for this? I've run into the same problem today and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Using your initial (simple) example, you can do:

```
In [29]: s1.update(pd.Series(lookup))

In [30]: s1
Out[30]:
p1       keep
p2    altered
p3    changed
dtype: object
```